# Access private IP based app

Tags: ip, database, private-network

I need to access a web based application whos ip is 10.2.201.123 and the port for it is 9080. And as some body said that I need to be part of that network but as you can see network has a private ip. If I become part it means that I have to b same ip address as that network have database tag include cause thats application have its own database

Comment: You can if you are in the same network. With that I mean exactly that network not another private with the same IP range. Might be that I did not understand your question so please clarify.

Comment: What do you mean by "access"? Copy / run? Why do you have database tag? This type of access is surely possible. Are you interested to set up a share,  or do you need to access it. Please edit your question and clarify these.

Comment: This would depend on how the network is configured. A router could have been configured to recognise requests to this private ip and direct them where needed. More clarity is needed on the question

Comment: Private IP's will not route across the internet.  As long as it is local OK.  Also you can connect 2 networks over VPN, and then inside of the VPN you could connect.  However, VPN uses 2 public IP to setup and maintain the connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is in a private network you can not connect directly to it from other network . You have different possibilities:

- You will need a VPN to their network. So you can access to the
  resources in their LAN.
- The NetworkAdmin can create A NAT in their router/firewall to
  redirect the traffic to the db. You will need their public address.

Comment: Thank you so much do I have any otwr way then vpn r nating???

Comment: If you are out of their network, you can not reach that IP unless you connect via VPN or there is a NAT (port forwarding) redirecting from their public IP to that resource (DB)